# Javascript for adding a custom attribute to some elements

Tags: javascript

Given a section of HTML, can I selectively pick some types of elements (e.g., input) and add a custom attribute using JavaScript? I would also need to remove this attribute if it exists.

I have done this before using jQuery, but I'm unable to use it for this particular task.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[Accessing HTML attributes using the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml)

```
element.hasAttribute('foo');
element.getAttribute('foo');
element.setAttribute('foo', value);
element.removeAttribute('foo');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="first-div">
<p class="first-p">Hello!
</p>
</div>
```

Adding attribute via javascript:

```
var myDiv= document.getElementsByClassName("first-div")[0];
var myp= myDiv.children[0];
nyp.setAttribute('myAttribute','valueForAttribute');
```

getting the attribute via javascript:

```
   console.log(myp.getAttribute('myAttribute'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look here how to get and set the attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/tuc57hbp/6/

to get attribute you must first get the `<td>` value. Then you must get it's `input` children using `td.children[0]` and set the `input` children `attribute` value using `input.setAttirbute('dummy', 'value')`.
Then retrieve it using `getAttribute('dummy')`.

Answer (score -1):

```
el.attribute = value
```

is all there is to it. The attribute is created if it does not exist.

Comment: This sets a _property_ to the `HTMLElement` object. It doesn't set an _attribute_. Use `setAttribute ( name, value )`.

Comment: What's the difference practically?

Comment: @GergőHorváth Maybe when using querySelector, because you can query in attributes

Comment: @GergőHorváth see [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)