# Javascript: add attribute method question

Tags: javascript, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript setAttribute vs .attribute=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/javascript-setattribute-vs-attribute)

Should I prefer one of these two methods to add attributes?

```
input.name='amount';

input.setAttribute('name', 'amount');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setAttribute doesn't work correctly in IE

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute):

> Using setAttribute() to modify certain attributes, most notably value
>   in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default
>   value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the
>   properties. For example, use elt.value instead of
>   elt.setAttribute('value', val).

I guess it would be better to access attributes directly, since that is what the DOM is designed for...

Comment: `setAttribute` is a [DOM Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) method. `.value` is a [HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) attribute defined in the DOM HTML extension. So both are part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla supports only setAttribute(). So if you are designing a multi-browser supporting page, it will be good to have an if condition checking the Browser Name, and call the function/assignments as per that.

Comment: `setAttribute` *should* work in every browser. It is a DOM element method: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614  Just saying this so that no one gets the false impressions that `setAttribute` is a Mozilla *only* method.

Comment: @FelixKling "Mozilla supports only `setAttribute()`" vs. "Only Mozilla supports `setAttribute()`".