# What is the difference between setAttribute and dot notation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

Why do you sometimes set an attribute like this:

```
x.type = "submit";
```

and other times like this:

```
x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
```

I always figured it didn't matter which way, but I'm having an issue doing this:

```
x.onClick = save;
```

but when I switch it to this it works:

```
x.setAttribute("onClick", "save()");
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018814/setting-a-property-via-property-or-setattribute, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: `x.onClick = save` does not work because JavaScript is **case-sensitive**. The property is `onclick`: `x.onclick = save;`. HTML is **not** case-sensitive, so `<... onclick="save()">`, `<... onClick="save()">` and `<... ONCLICK="save()">` are all the same.

Comment: This might help as well to understand the differences between HTML attributes and DOM properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setAttribute` only works on DOM elements and lowercases the attribute name on HTML elements. And you can't use dot notation to assign values to dynamic attribute names.

And there's also this:

> Using `setAttribute()` to modify certain attributes, most notably value
>   in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default
>   value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the
>   properties. For example, use `elt.value` instead of
>   `elt.setAttribute('value', val)`.

Comment: So as a general rule, if I experience the save issue I had above, it's probably a casing issue on the property itself and I need to investigate there first?

Comment: @LJM: If it's an HTML element, yes.

Comment: @LJM: Interacting with the DOM directly is the preferred way. All that you are doing with `setAttribute` is to add a new or change a attribute node and the browser will update the properties of the DOM element accordingly. Accessing these properties directly makes more sense.

Comment: So, as I understand it, calling setAttribute will update the underlying HTML. The browser will then refresh the DOM element.  So by using setAttribute, we're actually going out of our way when we could just update the DOM directly?

Comment: @LJM: It's not updating the HTML, since this is simply text, but I think you basically understood it. The browser creates a DOM from the HTML. For each attribute of an HTML element, the browser creates a corresponding attribute node. Then the *properties* of the corresponding element node are initialised based on the values of its attribute nodes. If you add or change an attribute node, the browser updates the properties accordingly. Not for all attributes, but for most of them afaik. To come back to your actually question, the dot notation is just one way of accessing properties in JavaScript

Comment: There are various issue with `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` which make it generally preferable to use properties instead. See other questions linked to in the comments.