# whats a difference between storing data in variable attached to Dom element vs storing data in attribute like data?

Tags: javascript, html

What are the benefits or cost of doing this:

`document.getElementById('asd').myData=123`

then `document.getElementById('asd').myData; //123`

vs

```
document.getElementById('asd').setAttribute('data-item',123);
document.getElementById('asd').getAttribute('data-item'); //123
```

Also where is data exactly being stored when i attach it dom element as variable.

Comment: @Paul S Linked question's answer no where tell: The difference in these two, or how attaching variables to dom works. The answer just says "You should always use attribute"

Comment: There are many other duplicates also; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886820/what-is-the-difference-between-setattribute-and-dot-notation-in-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151560/what-is-happening-behind-setattribute-vs-attribute), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018814/setting-a-property-via-property-or-setattribute) etc.