# Change attribute on tags of certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have this code:

```
<div class="changingClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="changingClass"></div>
```

For divs that have the class "changingClass", I want to add an attribute:

```
<div class="changingClass" myAttr="added attribute"></div>
```

How can I do this with javascript?

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: can you make use of any of the modern javascript libraries: Ex jQuery.

I do recommend to do so as maintaining compatibility across all browsers is not an easy trick when using pure javascript.

Comment: Definitely open to using JQuery - how would you suggest doing that? Please just submit and answer and I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery...

```
$('.changingClass').attr('myAttr', 'added attribute');
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('changingClass');
for (i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute('data-myAttr') = 'addedAttribute';
}
```

Please note that this will find, and then iterate over, all elements with the `className` of 'changingClass', and then add the `data-myAttr` attribute, and set it to `addedAttribute`. I use `data-myAttr` for compliance with the html5 user-defined `data-` attributes (which *should* allow the page to have valid DOM structure).

I've amended the above code to a slightly more compliant (Chromium 14, Opera 11.50 and Firefox 7 all on Ubuntu 11.04):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('changingClass'), myAttr;

for (i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    myAttr = document.createAttribute('data-myAttr');
    myAttr.nodeValue = 'addedAttribute';
    elems[i].setAttributeNode(myAttr);

}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3aKv5/2/), note that the css in this demo only seems to work in Firefox and Opera, *not* Chromium.

Comment: [`d.gEBCN()` is not 100% cross-browser (read: `!@#$ing` IE) compatible.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t10)

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName( "changingClass" );
for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    divs[i].setAttribute( "myAttr", "added attribute" );
    // Another option: divs[i].myAttr = "added attribute";
}
```

You can use the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) method. The getElementsByClassName selector is not support in all browsers though--IE. You can make your own [className selector](http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/) or you can use a framework such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) if you want full browser support.

Comment: [Do not use `setAttribute`. Use direct `.attrName = 'foo'` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/javascript-setattribute-vs-attribute)