# CreateElement with id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify this code to also give this div item an ID, however I have not found anything on google, and idName does not work. I read something about *append*, however it seems pretty complicated for a task that seems pretty simple, so is there an alternative? Thanks :)

```js
g = document.createElement('div');
g.className = 'tclose';
g.v = 0;
```

Comment: Or do you mean `g.id = 'foo';`?

Comment: I now know that I meant the ladder :)

Comment: [This Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=javascript+assign+id+to+dom+element) returns some reasonable results.

Answer (score 805, accepted):

You should use the [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method:

```
g = document.createElement('div');
g.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
```

Comment: With this code, we are creating not only the element ID but also for all attributes of the element.

Comment: @Mai Can you explain further? I can't understand the sentence.

Comment: @mystrdat I think Mai is trying to say that setAttribute() can be used to create the other attributes of an element and not just the id.

Comment: Why is this better than `g.id = "Div1")`?

Answer (score 157):

You can use `g.id = 'desiredId'` from your example to set the id of the element you've created.

Comment: I always thing that the annwer with less code is the best. More shot is not possible. thx.

Comment: this way you can add variables from you array too if you have any, Thanks

Answer (score 82):

```
var g = document.createElement('div');
g.id = 'someId';
```

Answer (score 57):

You can use [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Examples:

`g.setAttribute("id","yourId")`

`g.setAttribute("class","tclose")`

---

Here's my function for doing this better:

```
function createElement(element, attribute, inner) {
  if (typeof(element) === "undefined") {
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof(inner) === "undefined") {
    inner = "";
  }
  var el = document.createElement(element);
  if (typeof(attribute) === 'object') {
    for (var key in attribute) {
      el.setAttribute(key, attribute[key]);
    }
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(inner)) {
    inner = [inner];
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < inner.length; k++) {
    if (inner[k].tagName) {
      el.appendChild(inner[k]);
    } else {
      el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inner[k]));
    }
  }
  return el;
}
```

---

**Example 1:**

```
createElement("div");
```

will return this:

```
<div></div>
```

**Example 2:**

```
createElement("a",{"href":"http://google.com","style":"color:#FFF;background:#333;"},"google");`
```

will return this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="color:#FFF;background:#333;">google</a>
```

**Example 3:**

```
var google = createElement("a",{"href":"http://google.com"},"google"),
    youtube = createElement("a",{"href":"http://youtube.com"},"youtube"),
    facebook = createElement("a",{"href":"http://facebook.com"},"facebook"),
    links_conteiner = createElement("div",{"id":"links"},[google,youtube,facebook]);
```

will return this:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
    <a href="http://youtube.com">youtube</a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>
</div>
```

---

You can create new elements and set attribute(s) and append child(s)

```
createElement("tag",{attr:val,attr:val},[element1,"some text",element2,element3,"or some text again :)"]);
```

There is no limit for attr or child element(s)

Comment: Why on Earth would you pass the attributes with your own syntax [which you have to parse], when you can use a standard object? Plus, if you need to create a lot of elements, you need a templating system [e.g. Handlebars] and not overcomplicated functions.

Comment: This function is one of the first from my functions and I have not thought about updating. I think your idea is better and I will definitely change it. Thank you for that.

Comment: Although they're right, thanks for providing additional information and alternate ways of going about it. Very insightful.

Comment: I prefer use `myCreatedElement.id = "myId";` more informations at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36581696/6614155

Answer (score 15):

Why not do this with jQuery?

```
var newDiv= $('<div/>', { id: 'foo', class: 'tclose'})
```

Comment: not everyone can or wants to use jQuery.  But if he were, he could just do var g = $('<div id="blah" class="tclose">');

Comment: @BradleyMountford : He tagged the question with jQuery. thay's i suggested a jQuery solution

Comment: Although the specification does not forbid the usage of reserved keywords as property names, it might still be better to put `class` in quotes.

Comment: Is this greater than `g.id="desiredId"`? I think so. `g = $('<div id="blah" class="tclose">');` is great too.

Answer (score 8):

```
var element = document.createElement('tagname');    

element.className= "classname";
element.id= "id";
```

try this you want.

Answer (score 5):

that is simple, just to make a new element with an id :

```
var myCreatedElement = document.createElement("div");
var myContainer = document.getElementById("container");

//setAttribute() is used to create attributes or change it:
myCreatedElement.setAttribute("id","myId");

//here you add the element you created using appendChild()
myContainer.appendChild(myCreatedElement);
```

that is all

Comment: Why don't you set the `id` as `myCreatedElement.id = "myId";`

Comment: the element you would create would be unknown element, like the **SVG** element in some browsers it is unknown element so you can't put the id for unknown element.

Comment: Your response to my question does not make much sense. You are doing `myCreatedElement.setAttribute("id","myId");` which is equivalent to the simpler `myCreatedElement.id = "myId";`. So, you are setting the `id` anyway. So, why don't you do so using a more conventional and elegant way, rather than the unintuitive and unnecessary use of `setAttribute`?

Comment: I've once created svg element using ```createElement('svg')``` and returned _[object HTMLUnknownElement]_ tried to make ```svg.id``` but failed.I don't know if the problem was from my browser or test environment but failed... why? don't know.

Comment: Do you remember the error message?

Comment: no, I don't remember..

Answer (score 4):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var g = document.createElement('div');
    g.setAttribute("id", "google_translate_elementMobile");
    
  document.querySelector('Selector will here').appendChild(g);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you are trying to set an ID so you can style it in CSS but if that's the case what you can also try:

```
var g = document.createElement('div');    

g.className= "g";
```

and that will name your div so you can target it.