# Assign a name to a div created through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a div and giving it some styles like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.style.border = "2px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)";
```

Is there a way to assign a name to this div so I can reference it in other places, like in other JavaScript code or in CSS?

**Update**

Now doing this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    div.style.color = "white";
    div.style.border = "2px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)";
    div.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
});
```

and am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on `div.setAttribute("id", "Div1");`

Comment: Usually you should use the `id` property.

Comment: Could you give an example? How can I change this div using JavaScript outside of this function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422974/createelement-with-id

Says div.setAttribute('id', 'MyId');

Comment: The name attribute isn't valid for a div.

Comment: Ok, so after setting my ID, how can I do something like: `document.getElementById(myNewDiv).innerHTML = 'My Text';` ?

Comment: You would do it exactly like that if `myNewDiv` was a variable. Otherwise quote it `document.getElementById('myNewDiv').innerHTML = 'My Text';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML element (dynamically created or not), is usually identified by the `id` attribute. An unique identifier that distinguishes the element from every other on the page.

In your case it could be set like:

```
div.setAttribute("id", "myDivId");
```

Then, you can target this element. For an example in CSS you use the syntax `#id`, so like:

```
#myDivId {
    color: red;
}
```

Or in JavaScript you could access this element by the `document.getElementById()` function:

```
var d = document.getElementById("myDivId");
d.style.color = "red";
```