# How can I use JS to create a HTML element with a ID?

Tags: javascript, html

For example I want to use JS to create a HTML element with a id inside of a div on my website when the user clicks a button.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, a quick search on Google leads you to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422974/createelement-with-id

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload=function(){//if the page is loaded
var button=document.getElementById("buttonone");//get your button #buttonone or some other id
button.onclick=function(){
 var div=document.createElement("div");
 div.id="test";
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 };
};
```

I dont explain it as it is self explaining...

Comment: It self-explains that every new element will have the same `id`, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by createElement function of javascript

```
var btn = document.createElement("DIV");        // Create a <div> element
btn.id="dynamic_id"
document.body.appendChild(btn);                    // Append <button> to <body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) like so:

```
var myNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
myNewDiv.id = "your-id";
```

Which will create a `<div id="your-id">`

If you want to insert it when a user clicks a button, then you can bind a function to that button: `<button onClick="createMyDiv()">Click me</button>`

And then in your javascript:

```
function createMyDiv(){
    var myNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    myNewDiv.id = "your-id";
    // Now you insert it 
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('target-div');
    parentDiv.appendChild(myNewDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)** like this:

```js
// Counter that will change with each new element so no 
// two elements will have the same ID
var counter = 1;

// function that can be called whenever a new element is needed
function makeElement(elementType){
  // Create a new element of the type passed in to the function
  // This can be hard-coded of course, but is shown this way
  // to show how this one function can be reused to make any kind of new element
  var newElem = document.createElement(elementType);
  
  // Set the id using the counter value and then increase the counter
  newElem.id = elementType + counter++;
  
  // Set the content of the element. Dependingn on the type of element being created
  /// other properties would need to be set (i.e. href for <a>, src for <img>, etc.)
  newElem.textContent = "I'm a new " + elementType + " with an ID of " + newElem.id;
  
  // Add the element to the document.
  // This can be inserted at any specific spot in the document you like.
  document.body.appendChild(newElem);
  
}

// Run the function several times to create various types of elements,
// each with different id's.
makeElement("div");
makeElement("span");
makeElement("h1");
makeElement("p");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createelement() {
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="yourid">Your Element</div>';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="createelement()">Create Element</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must get a reference of your container.
 Then, create a new element with createElement() and set the id of this newly created element.
Last, add the element to your container with appendChild().

```
const container = document.getElementById('myContainer'); 
const el = document.createElement('span');
el.id = 'myId';
container.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: This will cause all elements created by this code to have the same `id`, which isn't allowed.