# Give params to a div created via document.createElement

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to create multiple divs using a `for loop` which i do it like this

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let divs = document.createElement('div');
  divs.className = 'button';
  divs.data-id = (data[i]).id;                  // error
  document.body.appendChild(divs);
}
```

Now my issue is that `data-id` is required but it pops an error. So how can I define `data-id` dynamically

I also tried giving the whole div as innerHTML  of another div but then it wont render. So how can this be solved??

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23899918/4964262

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setAttribute()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) instead:

```
divs.setAttribute('data-id' , data[i].id);
```

Also note that hyphens are not allowed in Javascript identifiers, they would be parsed as substraction.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `divs.setAttribute('data-id', data[i].id);`.

If you were trying to read an attribute with a funky character such as that dash in your example, you would access it with brackets instead of dot notation and quote the attribute like so: `divs.attributes['data-id']`

Answer (score 2):

**This should work:**

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let divs = document.createElement('div');
  divs.setAttribute("id", "btn_id");
  divs.setAttribute("class", "btn_class");
  divs.setAttribute("data-id", (data[i]).id);
  document.body.appendChild(divs);
}
```

Or use Jquery alternatives:

> `var newDiv= $('<div/>', { id: 'foo', class: 'tclose'})`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let divs = document.createElement('div');
  var attr = document.createAttribute('data-id');
  attr.value = (data[i]).id;
  divs.setAttributeNode(attr);
  document.body.appendChild(divs);
}
```