# javascript cascading drop down and create text input box

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dropdown, cascading

I'm trying to create a cascading dropdown that includes the value "Others" as well. Upon user selecting 'Others' it should pop up a text input box for users to enter information manually and submit button.

I'm new to JavaScript so not sure if I'm doing this correctly below.

```js
var statesUSA = ["California", "Illinois", "Wisconsin", "Others"];
var statesCanada = ["Quebec", "Ontario", "Alberta", "Others"];

function checkvalue(val) {
  if (val === "Others")
    document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'none';
}

function countryChanged(country) {
  var selectState = document.getElementById('states');
  var ln = selectState.length - 1;
  while (ln > 0) {
    selectState.remove(1); //Remove all but "Select State"
    ln--;
  }

  var stateArray;

  switch (country) {
    case "USA":
      stateArray = statesUSA
      break;
    case "Canada":
      stateArray = statesCanada
      break;
    case "England":
      stateArray = statesEngland
      break;
    default:
  }

  for (i = 0; i < stateArray.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');

    option.text = stateArray[i];
    option.value = stateArray[i];

    /*option.text = checkvalue(stateArray[i]);
    option.value = checkvalue(stateArray[i]);*/

    selectState.add(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id='countries' onchange='countryChanged(this.value);'>
  <option value=''>Select Country</option>
  <option value='USA'>USA</option>
  <option value='Canada'>Canada</option>
</select>
<select id='states' onchange='stateChanged(this.value);'>
  <option value=''>Select State</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Where is your element with id 'color'?  It doesn't currently exist so there is no way for it to be displayed.

Comment: I’m trying to create a text input box when a user select a value “other” in the dropdown.

Comment: @Saloo, there is nothing indicating that you are creating an element with the ID of 'color'.  You need to first create and element (like you do with 'option') but then you need to set the id property to 'color'.  Once you've done this, you can call your function to check the value and display the created element.  If you don't know how to set the ID property, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422974/createelement-with-id