# Why won't JavaScript function create an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a method, which is meant to create divs within another div... However it won't work...

Here is the method:

```
populateSquares(){
    let relatedTagToPopulation = document.getElementById("questionp");
    let whatTextIs = relatedTagToPopulation.textContent;
    for (let u=0;u<this.stemQuestions.length;u++){
        if (this.stemQuestions[u]==whatTextIs){
            var populateSquaresPertinentInt = u;
        }
    }
    for  (let i=0;i<this.stemAnswers.length;i++){
        if (i==populateSquaresPertinentInt){
            let numberOfSquaresToAdd = this.stemAnswers[i].length;
            for (let j=0;j<numberOfSquaresToAdd;j++){
                let elToAdd = document.createElement("<div id='ans"+j+"' class='lans'></div>"); 
                let elToAddInto = document.getElementById("answeri"); 
                elToAddInto.appendChild(elToAdd); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives out this error...

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<div id='ans0' class='lans'></div>') is not a valid name.
```

Comment: `createElement` takes a tag name, like `"div"`, not HTML. You would assign attributes separately.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JavaScript, you should follow the document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement, and here: [CreateElement with id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422974/createelement-with-id)

```
let elToAdd = document.createElement('div')
// then call `elToAdd.xxxx` to add attributes or do other operation on the element
elToAdd.setAttribute("id", "ans" + i);
// ... more
```

If you are using jQuery, you can use:

```
let elToAdd = jQuery("<div id='ans"+j+"' class='lans'></div>")
```

Comment: Note that the `id` attribute is also reflected by a property, so you can do: `elToAdd.id = "ans" + j`

Answer (score 1):

## Three Ways to Create Tags

**The following examples all do the same thing:<sup>✱</sup>**
Create an `<article>` tag with the class: `.post` and add it to the `<main id="main">` tag.
<sup><sup>✱</sup> There's an exception see #2 `.innerHTML`</sup>

---

### [`document.createElement(tagName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

The only parameter is a `tagName` (ex. `"DIV"`, `"SPAN"`, `"IFRAME"`, etc.). Once created it needs to be added to the DOM:

> ```
> const post = document.createElement("ARTICLE");
> post.className = "post";
> document.getElementById('main').appendChild(post);
> ```

This is an old yet stable method but it takes two lines to create one barebones tag. More code is necessary to assign attributes and content.

---

### [`.innerHTML += htmlString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

This property will parse a tag(s) out of a given String within the targeted tag. If an `=` operator is used all content of the targeted tag is overwritten with the `htmlString`. If `+=` operator is used the `htmlString` will be appended to the content within the targeted tag.

> ```
> document.querySelector('main').innerHTML += `<article class='post'></article>`;
> ```

This pattern is simple and versatile. In one line multiple tags can be created with attributes and content. It's limited to either overwriting content: `=` or appending to content: `+=`.

**<sup>✱</sup>Edit:** Kaiido has informed me that `.innerHTML` will replace everything so if you are concerned about event bindings or references don't use it. See comments below.

---

### [`.insertAdjacentHTML(position, htmlString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

This is `.innerHTML` on steroids. It will insert before/after/inside/outside a given `htmlString` of a targeted tag. The first parameter is one of four strings that determine the position of insertion relative to the targeted tag:

> ```
> "beforebegin" <div id="target"> "afterbegin" text content "beforeend" </div> "afterend"
> ```

The second parameter is the `htmlSting` to be inserted.

> ```
> document.getElementsByTagName('MAIN')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
>   <article class='post'></article>
> `);
> ```

---

I couldn't follow your code but it's supposed to be a method? So the demo has an object called `populate` and there's a factory function called `documentSection()` that creates objects and inherits the method `.createSection()` from `populate`.

### Demo

```js
let text = ['post 1', 'post 2', 'post 3'];
let archives = ['document 1', 'document 2', 'document 3'];

const populate = content => ({
  createSections: () => {
    let idx = 0;
    const target = document.querySelector("main");
    /* 
    Pattern 1 - document.createElement(tagName)
    */
    const section = document.createElement('SECTION');
    section.id = content.title;
    target.appendChild(section);
    /*
    Pattern 2 - .innerHTML += htmlString
    */
    section.innerHTML += `<h2>${content.title}</h2>`;
    for (let text of content.text) {
      idx++;
      /*
      Pattern 3 - .insertAdjacentHTML(position, htmlString)
      */
      section.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<article id="${content.title}-${idx}" class="t">${text}</article>`);
    }
  }
});

const documentSection = (title, text) => {
  let content = {
    title: title,
    text: text
  };
  return Object.assign(content, populate(content));
};

const post = documentSection('Post', text);
const archive = documentSection('Archive', archives);

post.createSections();
archive.createSections();
```

```css
main {
  display: table;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
  padding: 2px 10px 10px;
}

h1 {
  font: 900 small-caps 1.5rem/1 Tahoma;
  margin-bottom: 8px
}

h2 {
  font: 700 small-caps 1.2rem/1 Tahoma;
  margin-bottom: 8px
}

section {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 2px 8px 8px;
}

article {
  font: 400 1rem/1.25 Arial;
}

.t::before {
  content: attr(id)': ';
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Documents</h1>
</main>
```

Comment: Nope, #2 doesn't do the same thing at all. From the DOM point of view, it does remove the <main> element and all its children, and then append a new one, with the same markup, along with new elements that do share the same markup as the children of the previous <main> and a new <article> element. If you had any variable pointing to one of these children, the element they point to is now off-doc. If you had any event listeners, they're gone.

Comment: Duly noted, sir, thank you. @Kaiido does `.innerText` and `.textContent` wipeout anything with `+=` ?