# Reading values from input fields created in an array with document.createElement()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a table that the user can hit "new line" to create a new row of the table. I do this by foo.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));

```
function newLine() {
  sArr.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));
  sArr[sArr.length-1].setAttribute("type", "text");
  document.body.appendChild(sArr[sArr.length-1]);

  gArr.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));
  gArr[gArr.length-1].setAttribute("type", "text");
  document.body.appendChild(gArr[gArr.length-1]);

  tArr.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));
  tArr[tArr.length-1].setAttribute("type", "text");
  document.body.appendChild(tArr[tArr.length-1]);
  //alert(sArr.length+", "+gArr.length+", "+tArr.length);
  var x = document.createElement("br");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}

function calc(){
  var temp = 0;
  var total = 0;

  for(i = 0; i<sArr.length; i++){
    total = total + calc2(i);
  }

  var o = document.getElementById("output");
  o.value = total;
}

function calc2(i){
  alert(i);
  var s = document.getElementById(sArr[i]);
  var g = document.getElementById(gArr[i]);
  var t = document.getElementById(tArr[i]);
  var VO2walkmin = 3.28; 
  var VO2rest = 3.05; 
  var C1 = 0.32;
  var C2 = 0.19;
  var C3 = 2.66;
  var Cdecline = 0.73;
  var s2 = s.value;
  var g2 = g.value;
  var t2 = t.value;
  var negGrade = g.value;

  if(g2 < 0){g2 = 0};

  VO2move = ((C1 * g2)+VO2walkmin)+((1+(C2*g2))*(C3*(s2^2)));

  VO2inc = VO2rest+(t2*VO2move);

  VO2dec = VO2rest+(Cdecline*(t2*VO2move))

  //var o = document.getElementById("output");

  return VO2inc;
}
```

When run, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

from line 66. Specifically, this line:

```
var s2 = s.value;
```

I'm struggling to find my mistake here... and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It means the line above with `document.getElementById(sArr[i])` didn't find any element with that ID in your document, because `sArr[i]` is an object, not a string.  Assign an attribute "id" if you want to get elements by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new element, but it has no ID. And so you can't fetch it by ID. The result of `document.getElementById(sArr[i])` will be null.

Check this answer to see how ID can be assigned to a newly created element:

[Create element with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422974/createelement-with-id)

Comment: Why add an ID when you can just access the element directly from the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `document.getElementById`. `sArr[i]` is the input element itself, not its ID, so you can just read its value directly.

```
var s = sArr[i];
var g = gArr[i];
var t = tArr[i];
```