# JavaScript change img src attribute without jQuery

Tags: javascript, image, src

How to change the `src` attribute of a `HTMLImageElement` in JavaScript?

I need help to convert `logo.attr('src','img/rm2.png')` to vanilla JavaScript.

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1536) {
        var logo = document.getElementById('rm');
        logo.attr('src','img/rm2.png');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You mean you want to use pure javascript?

This should do it:

```
var logo = document.getElementById('rm');
logo.src = "img/rm2.png";
```

So your function should look like :

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1536) {
      var logo = document.getElementById('rm');
      logo.src = "img/rm2.png";
    }
};
```

**Note**: You could also use [element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).  BUT, see this post for more:
[When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/javascript-setattribute-vs-attribute)

Comment: dang it, beat me by 8 seconds :)

Comment: :) Yea the JS/JQuery questions really have too many people fighting to [shoot an answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 1):

try this...hope it works

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1536) {
        var logo = document.getElementById('rm');
        logo.setAttribute('src','img/rm2.png');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just `logo.src = "img/rm2.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var logo = document.getElementById('rm');
logo.setAttribute('src', 'img/rm2.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want to do this in different places of the program, I would create a function like this:

```
function ChangeImage(image_id,path)
{
  document.images[image_id].src = path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to check if the size has changes and then changes back check code bellow.

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {

      var logo = document.getElementById('changeLeft');
      logo.src = "MobileImage.png";

    }else{

 var logo = document.getElementById('changeLeft');
      logo.src = "DesktopImage.png";

    }
};
```

Adjust window.innerWidth to decide on your break points.
Hope that helps.