# add a image from a url to a gallery html using js

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am new to javascript and have looked but can't seem to solve my problem.
I am looking to ask the user for a url to an image and add it to a gallery made using html and another js document. The gallery is fine just need to figure out a way to add a new img tag with the url inside it.

This is what i have so far:

```
function getUrl() {
var url = prompt('Enter image URL');

if (url) { // Do string and URL validation here and also for image type
    return url;
} else {
    return getUrl();
}`.slider image.src = getUrl();`



    <form action="" method="post" class="contact" id="contact" onsubmit="return getUrl()">
    <label for="name">Add Image url:</label>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

<div class="slider">
    <img src="gallery/img1.jpg" alt="image 1" />
    <img src="gallery/img2.jpg" alt="image 2" />
    <img src="gallery/img3.jpg" alt="image 3" />
    <img id="image"/>

    <button class="prev">&#60;</button>
    <button class="next">&#62;</button>
 </div>
```

If you can help in anyway that would be great, thanks.

edit: My question was i wanted to add img tags to a gallery already in the html code but by not changing the src of any photos already there and just adding the tag each time a photo was added with the url of the photo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript change img src attribute without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731728/javascript-change-img-src-attribute-without-jquery)

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new image tag and insert before the prev button into the slider by

```
    var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];
      slider.insertBefore(img,document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0]);
```

**Note:** Javascript doesn't requires a form submit to execute. we can make it ru on any event like `onclick` `onmouseover`

**DEMO:-**

```js
function getUrl() {
var url = prompt('Enter image URL');

if (url) { // Do string and URL validation here and also for image type
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;

    var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];
      slider.insertBefore(img,document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0]);
} else {
    return getUrl();
}//`.slider image.src = getUrl();`
}
```

```html
    <label for="name">Add Image url:</label>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="getUrl();">

<div class="slider">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69cf2e00c81bc89731652db2b9ca1dbf?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="image 1" />
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69cf2e00c81bc89731652db2b9ca1dbf?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="image 2" />
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69cf2e00c81bc89731652db2b9ca1dbf?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="image 3" />
    <img id="image"/>

    <button class="prev">&#60;</button>
    <button class="next">&#62;</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: It worked man thanks very much, not alone that but i understand what you  did also so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
Var img = Document.createElement("img");
Img.src = 'your url';

Var div = document.getElementById("imagesDiv");
Div.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i am looking to add a image into the slider div below the images already there and putting the src= "imputed url". I am new to this so this is why i am finding it hard to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I might still be not understanding what you want, but in case you want to append the url to an image that's already under the three images, just use :  var img = document.getElementById("image");   Img.src = "your url"; @JohnOKeeffe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.slider').append(
                     $('<img></img>').
                     attr('src', yourUrl).
                     attr('alt', yourAlt)
                    );
```

Just don't forget add link to jQuery in the header of your html page, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```