# Javascript button slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to the javascript programming so can someone help me.
This is my code

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var pic = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', colorIt, false);

function colorIt(e) {
  pic.innerHTML="src=/'https://picturejs.org/adv/banner.jpg\' width=\'400px\' height=\'150px\'>";

}
```

```html
<div id="picture">
  <img src="" id="picture" style="display:none;"> 
</div>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: you should set the src attribute like so pic.src = "YOUR_IMG_URL"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript change img src attribute without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731728/javascript-change-img-src-attribute-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `colorIt` function to the following. You need to set the `src` and then set the `display` to block. You might also want to move the `height` and `width` to CSS.

```
function colorIt(e) {
  pic.src='https://picturejs.org/adv/banner.jpg';
  pic.width = 400;
  pic.height = 150;
  pic.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fillIt(e) {
  pic.innerHTML="src=/'https://picturejs.org/adv/banner.jpg\' width=\'400px\' height=\'150px\'>";

}
```

The Source for the image in JavaScript is invalid. You used HTML hyperlinks in JS.

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` modifies the content *between* the opening and closing tags (`<div>THIS</div>`), not the content of the tag itself (`<div THIS></div>`).

You can modify the tags attribute using  `setAttribute` or by setting a property directly:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var pic = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', colorIt, false);

function colorIt(e) {
  pic.src='https://picturejs.org/adv/banner.jpg'
  pic.width='400px' 
  pic.height='150px'

}
```

```html
<div id="picture">
  <img src="" id="picture" style="display:none;"> 
</div>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
function fillIt(e) {
  pic.style.display = "block";
  pic.src ="https://libertycity.net/uploads/download/gta5_lamborghini/thumbs/4qhllsfhd8fk9bm4mf36761u37/15205818409903_63e23c-pgta535987529.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. However, you need to set each property in JS.

> ALso I could not get `picturejs.org` to load so I placed a `picsum` pic in there instead.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var pic = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', colorIt, false);

function colorIt(e) {
  pic.src='https://picsum.photos/150/400'
  pic.width='400' 
  pic.height='150';
  pic.style.display='block';

}
```

```html
<div id="picture">
  <img src="" id="picture" style="display:none;"> 
</div>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the root of your image in  , for example  depeding on where you have the image downloaded in your PC.

Hope this helps !