# IE 9 getAttribute method working

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am setting a custom attribute named (say) titleDiv by using setAttribute method

HTML code : 
`<div id="Object" titleDiv="blank"></div>`

Javascript code :

`var Object=document.getElementById('Object');
Object.setAttribute("titleDiv","myDiv");`

Which works fine in all the browser other than IE 9. 
Same thing happens for getAttribute also.

I have extensive use custom  attributes like above in my code and I am not supposed to change the structure.

Is there any alternative way to write above code so that IE will understand it?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think IE9 isn't doing that? Works for me, provided you use an actual DOM element and not literally `Object`: http://jsbin.com/ujadaj/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ujadaj/1)).

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: @BillyMoat: That's *specifically* the `class` attribute, which IE8 and earlier had real issues with, but fortunately it's reflected via a property called `className`.

Comment: get/setAttribute has been broken in IE for ages. Using non-standard attributes is also not a good idea (since you can reliably read and set standard properties using dot notation) which is why the *class* and *data–* attributes exist. But I guess you have no choice in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer** based on question edit:

You're using an identifier you *really* should stay away from: `Object`. I would recommend changing both the `id` *and* the name of the variable you use. So:

```
<div id="theObject" titleDiv="blank"></div>
```

and

```
var theObject=document.getElementById('theObject');
theObject.setAttribute("titleDiv","myDiv");
```

`Object` is a built-in function in JavaScript. Since the `id` of elements gets dumped into the global namespace, I would avoid using any of the built-in JavaScript functions (`Object`, `Function`, `Date`, etc.) as `id` values. For similar reasons, not least just so you're not confusing yourself and others, I would stay away from them as variable names.

That said, I [couldn't replicate the problem](http://jsbin.com/ujadaj/2) ([source](http://jsbin.com/ujadaj/2/edit)), so although I would still change the `id` and variable name, that may not be the problem. See also below.

---

**Original Answer**:

You call `setAttribute` on the DOM element instance. You don't do it via the built-in `Object` function.

If you use a DOM element, it works (even on IE9):

```
(function() {
  // Get an actual DOM element
  var target = document.getElementById("target");

  // Set the attribute
  target.setAttribute("titleDiv","myDiv");

  // Show the result
  display("Result: " + target.getAttribute("titleDiv"));

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ujadaj/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ujadaj/1)

If you use the F12 developer tools and go to the HTML tab, you can see that the `div` does actually get the attribute. (Be sure to use dev tools, **not** "view source" -- "view source" will show you the HTML that was sent from the server, not the current state of the DOM.)

---

Side note: Using nonstandard attributes that don't use [the `data-` prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) is a bad idea. You might want to feed that information up the chain to whoever is dictating this. But that's almost certainly not the problem you're having.

Comment: Actually my problem is that I am writing a simple drag drop application and at the drag end I call a function with id of the dragged item which is a simple string. When I alert that id on IE it shows me function itemId() { [native code] }. What is this?

Comment: @user1079065: I'm not following you. What does that have to do with the question / answer?

Comment: I thought that IE is not getting getAttribute but problem is different . It understands getAttribute it is not getting the string which I am passing as attrib to my drag end function

Comment: @user1079065: I just saw the question edit. I've edited the answer.

Comment: +1 for non–standard attribute advice. For the OP, so you have something to argue with: HTML5 introduced 18 new attributes for input elements, so you can't be sure that current non–standard attributes won't be in some future version of HTML. A particular browser might also introduce its own new attributes (that's how the web moves forward) in the hope they will become standardised in future. The golden rule is *do not modify objects you don't own* (host, built-in or native objects from someone else's code) and use only the API, properties and attributes you are provided.

Comment: @user1079065: IE **does** understand `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`, as I showed in my examples. Those work on IE9. IE does have several problems with those functions (mostly in IE8 and earlier), but on this. (On other things, like the `class` attribute.)