# Call JQuery function with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have following JS function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            var imageName="facebook-default-no-profile-pic.jpg";
            var name="xxx";
                            var age="111";
            $.fancybox.open([{
                href : '<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>image,
                title : name+' '+age
            }]);
        });

    });
 </script>
```

I use this function as HREF link as follows and it works fine.

```
<a id="fancybox-manual-a" href="javascript:;">Click</a>
```

But I want to parse some arguments(values for **name** and **age**) when I call **fancybox-manual-a** function. How can I do ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. I want to parse arguments for fancybox-manual-a function

Comment: Parse what arguments? You'll need to give more context than that.

Comment: `fancybox-manual-a` is not a function!!!. To declare a function, use the `function` keyword in the `script` context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you want to set some values from the `<a>` element and pick them up in the click handler. You can attach `data-*` attributes on the element and fetch them using `.data()`:

Append to your HTML like so:

```
<a id="fancybox-manual-a" href="#" data-foo="bar" data-baz="bam" data-some-long-name="someValue>Click</a>
```

Then use `.data()` to get them:

```
$("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data();

  var foo = data.foo;          //bar
  var baz = data.baz;          //bam
  var zee = data.someLongName; //someValue. Note the dash-separated to camelCase conversion

  ...
});
```

Comment: wow, is data-* a jquery feature? does if have to be called `data`?

Comment: No, it's an HTML5 feature. And yes, it has to start with *data-* in order to be valid markup. This also means that this answer is only valid if your document is an HTML5 document.

Comment: @OlegMikheev You can actually put any arbitrarily named attribute, though it will trip off validators. jQuery's `.data()` just transparently goes through the ones with `data-*`, making it a handy function.

Comment: `$(this).data()` is jquery function, does HTML5 provide any means to retrieve data without JS frameworks?

Comment: Is this a jquery function ?

Comment: HTML is a markup language, speaking of data retrieval makes no sense within HTML. However, Javascript is perfectly capable of reading such attributes even without any library in the same way any other attribute can be read. data attributes is an *official* HTML5 feature.

Comment: @OlegMikheev You can access the values directly, like `element['data-name']` or via `element.getAttribute('name')`. [Here's a post that explains which of the two to use](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3919291/575527).