# How to add many hotspost on an picture and save into database in .net mvc

Tags: .net, database, asp.net-mvc-5, point

I am create a website for customer sale everything on a picture(2D not 360 degrees), as the following.
Could you help me how to add any hotspost and save into database in MVC5.
Sorry, my English is bad.
Thank you much!
Here are example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnQIN.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ske.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hotspot are named `imagemap` in HTML.
Refer to this documentation https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_usemap.asp

After you have created the definition of you imagemap you can save and load the parameters from DB.
Then you can create the `map` from Javascript, look at this answer: [Dynamically create Image map via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447928/dynamically-create-image-map-via-javascript)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it.
Have a good day!