# Set placeholder value

Tags: javascript

I want to set the `placeholder` value to an `input` I am creating dynamically with javascript. How can I do that on creation ?

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.className = 'my-input-class';
input.placeholder ???
```

Comment: why ??? change it to = and your text

Comment: @Jois That actually works. My IDE was not recognizing that variable.

Comment: @Shiro - I have the correct answer, see the link I provided.  Please upvote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var Yourinput = document.createElement('input');
Yourinput.className = 'my-input-class';
Yourinput.placeholder = "Some text";
```

You can set it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setAttribute` method on the input:

```
input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Some Awesome Text');
```

or, since `.placeholder` has a getter and a setter on it, you can do this:

```
input.placeholder = 'Some Awesome Text';
```

Answer (score -1):

`input.placeholder = "your_value"` works for standard attributes otherwise use `setAttribute`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: This works. My IDE was not recognizing the `placeholder` variable because it wasn't set yet. Thanks.