# Html attribute value (of input) change doesn't affect value property

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, attributes

I have the single input tag and I have wrote following in my chrome console

[image]

This result unexpected for me. In book I have read I read that when I change html attibute then corresponding property shoul be changed. But then I shnage property, attribute should not be changed

---

**P.S.**
`$0` is feature of chrome and point to the selected element. I selected the input tag before script evaluating.

Comment: Try an actual element instead

Comment: @adeneo Does my element not actual?

Comment: The exact quote from the linked answer is: *In contrast, the value property doesn't reflect the value attribute.*

Answer (score -1):

The two strategies you've written have different purposes, and only `foo.value = bar` changes the DOM element. Using `setAttribute` just keeps the changes inside the JavaScript environment and doesn't change the DOM.

See this answer for a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36581696/1348109