# Disabling checkbox in onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have such problem,
I have  with type="checkbox" and also I'm using JAWS to read it. In IE11 JAWS read disabled checked checkbox as unchecked. I know that it is bug of IE so I need to delete attribute "disable" from  and replace it with some other logic that will disable checkbox. I tried to add

```
 document.getElementById("check").disabled= true;
```

to my onclick() function, but still I have possibility to uncheck checked checkbox first time. Then it became disabled. Also in my onClick() I have another several functions, so onclick will be run. Could someone suggest me any solution?

Comment: See also: [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36581696/4639281)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can [be done](https://jsfiddle.net/u2wfzu2j/) using `.setAttribute(attribute, value)`. Like so:

```
document.getElementById("check").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this older solution for IE:

```
document.getElementById("check").disabled = "disabled";
```

and to remove it:

```
document.getElementById("check").disabled = "";
```

or
    document.getElementById("check").disabled = false;