# Which of the following should be used: .attribute= vs setAttribute vs attr()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

.attribute in Javascript

```
let friendDiv = document.getElementById("friend");
friendDiv.className = "list";
```

**VS**

setAttribute in Javascript

```
let friendDiv = document.getElementById("friend");
friendDiv.setAttribute("class","list");
```

**VS**

.attr in Jquery

```
$("#friend").attr("class", "list");
```

Comment: Depends on whichever language you are comfortable with.

Comment: I would say `friendDiv.classList`, you could then use `.value`, `.add`, `.remove`, `.toggle`.. etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are trying to achieve, or which attribute you want to change

Normally the `setAttribute` versions are longer, so the shorter ones should be preferred.
Sometimes, there is a DOM property that is even more convenient than the `setAttribute` since it provides for methods, like [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
But you may want to add an attribute, that is not part of the DOM like `<span my-span-is-awesome></span>`. Here you have no other choice than using `setAttribute`.

I prefer not to use jQuery where I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this similar question/answers: [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

`setAttribute` and `getAttribute` are just needed for non-standard HTML attributes.

You should be using `.attribute` for standard attributes.

If you are using JQuery, you can always use `attr` because can be used for standard and non-standard attributes.

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test');

console.log('Accessing custom attribute with .attribute:', test.custom);
console.log('Accessing standard attribute with .attribute:', test.className);
console.log('Accessing custom attribute with getAttribute:', test.getAttribute('custom'));
console.log('Accessing standard attribute with getAttribute:', test.getAttribute('class'));
console.log('Accessing non-standard attribute with jquery attr:', $(test).attr('custom'));
console.log('Accessing standard attribute with jquery attr:', $(test).attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="myClass" custom="anything">My test</div>
```