# JS Make element disabled if === 1

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the button when number is 1, using setAttribue

```
let element = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(element)
element.setAttribute('id', 'bet-size')

let text = document.createTextNode('1')
element.appendChild(text)

let click = document.createElement('input')
click.setAttribute('type', 'button')
click.setAttribute('id', 'decrease')
document.body.appendChild(click)
click.disabled = true

click.addEventListener('click', () => {
element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) - 1
if (element.textContent !== 1) {
click.setAttribute('disabled', true)
} else if (element.textContent > 1)
click.setAttribute('disabled', false)
})
```

Which way would be optimal to remove the attribute disabled when number is > 1?

Comment: This may be a bad question, but when *which* number is `< 1`? In what variable is it stored?

Comment: And do you know about the `if` statement? If so, then have a go with it (and `else`)  to set the disabled attribute accordingly.

Comment: Why are you re-inventing `<input type="number" min="1" />`?

Comment: my div contains number

Comment: setAttribute vs .attribute is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: want to use only js

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal"? Is any of them not working as expected?

Comment: i would prefer to use setAttribute('disabled', '')

Answer (score -1):

Since disabled is either true or false, you can just check the value to see if its > 1 or not.

```
click.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    element.textContent = Number(element.textContent) - 1
    e.target.setAttribute("disabled",(Number(element.textContent) - 1 > 1));
})
```