# How to make an HTML attribute change depending on which option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a button change when a certain option from a drop-down is selected.

```js
document.getElementById("region").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("order-btn").product-code = this.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="option" id="option" required>
  <option value="1234d1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="amdk19">Option 2</option>
  <option value="akd1sk">Option 3</option>
  <option value="19sd91">Option 4</option>
  <option value="asjd91">Option 5</option>
  <option value="129e8j">Option 6</option>
</select>

<div class="btn-checkout">
  <button id="order-btn" type="submit" product-code="">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

What I need to happen is when an option is chosen from the drop-down, the product code associated with that option is put into the `product-code="HERE"` on the button.

For example, If I chose Option 2 on the drop-down, its product code `"amdk19"` would then be put into the button like this:

```
<button id="order-btn" type="sumbit" product-code="amdk19">
```

I think this can be done with JavaScript, but I could not figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your attempt and tell us what exactly is broken with it.

Comment: @JohannesH.
Hey I have tried using this:
<script>
        document.getElementById("region").onchange = function() {
    
        document.getElementById("order-btn").product-code=this.value;
    
}
    </script>

But I dont think js understands what the product-code is?

Comment: Yep, you're on the right track! You have to use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`, as shown in my answer! :)

Comment: @ACT22AC please avoid posting code in comment, it's very unreadable. You can [edit] your question and add formatted code in it as response to comments

Comment: Please note that `product-code` is not a valid custom attribute name, rendering your **HTML invalid**. Custom attribute names must start `data-`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work! You can't set attributes on the object directly, like you tried -- instead, you have to use `setAttribute` on the button. You can use `.value` on the dropdown to get the value of the selected option.

```js
document.getElementById("option").onchange = function() {
  const btn = document.getElementById("order-btn");
  // `this` refers to the dropdown, so you're getting the dropdown's selected value
  btn.setAttribute("product-code", this.value);
}

document.getElementById("order-btn").onclick = function() {
  // `this` refers to the button
  console.log(this.getAttribute("product-code"));
}
```

```html
<select name="option" id="option" required>
  <option selected disabled>Select An Option</option>
  <option value="1234d1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="amdk19">Option 2</option>
  <option value="akd1sk">Option 3</option>
  <option value="19sd91">Option 4</option>
  <option value="asjd91">Option 5</option>
  <option value="129e8j">Option 6</option>
</select>

<div class="btn-checkout">
  <button id="order-btn" type="submit" product-code="">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While you're correct that it works, you haven't bothered to explain how, or why, it works. So how is the OP - or any future visitor with a similar problem - supposed to learn?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica This code is relatively simple, it's just 3 self-explanatory lines -- but fair enough, I've added some explanation. I'd appreciate if y'all would remove your downvotes, though, that seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Without any explanation I found the answer to be "not useful," therefore I down-voted it; as you've improved the answer I've removed the down-vote. As for your statement that it's "*3 self-explanatory lines*" I'd argue that they're not so self-explanatory for OP and others unfamiliar with JavaScript.

Comment: Please don't suggest using inline event listeners. It's widely considered bad practice and really a no-go for any professional developer.

Comment: @connexo fair enough, I've changed it to match the code that the OP updated in their post. Would appreciate a change in vote :)

Answer (score -3):

As there are already answer to this. I would like to recommend you Jquery for easy dealing with javascript.

1. Include jquery cdn like this : [Adding  jquery CDN in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)
2. Add `id` to your `select` and `button`. [Adding Id in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp)
3. Then use jquery methods like this:

```js
$("#optionsOfSomething").on("change",function(e){

$("#order-btn").attr("product-code",$(this).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <select name="option" id="optionsOfSomething" required>
       <option value="1234d1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="amdk19">Option 2</option>
        <option value="akd1sk">Option 3</option>
         <option value="19sd91">Option 4</option>
         <option value="asjd91">Option 5</option>
           <option value="129e8j">Option 6</option>
            </select>
    
<div class="btn-checkout">
  <button id="order-btn" type="submit" product-code="">Checkout</button>
         </div>
```

Comment: OP is new to JavaScript. Why are you recommending to him a library that considers Javascript a prerequisite?

Comment: What benefit does jQuery offer that JavaScript - without the library - can more easily accomplish?

Comment: because learning javascript is always hard for begineers. jquery will make his life a lot easier.

Comment: I will still stick to my jquery theory as it is more readable for begineers. It is essential to learn the javascript no doubt on that but i believe jquery first aids on learning the javascript much easily than learning the javascript itself. @Spectric

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. People that learn jQuery first usually lack a solid understanding of what they're doing, which unnecessarily lengthens and complicates the process of learning Javascript. Also jQuery really is becoming a thing of the past that almost every serious developer tries to get rid of.