# Javascript getAttribute("value") does not return user input

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic, user-input

My problem is that in JavaScript, when requesting input field to which I have written e.g "abc":

```
input_obj // <input type="text" value="">
input_obj.getAttribute("value")  // returns: ""
input_obj.value                  // returns: "abc"
```

I want to get user input with **getAttribute()** but it does not update on the contrary to **.value** property. First one returns what's in the original HTML and the other what's currently on the screen.

Anyone knows how to get user input but with the use of attribute name in **string**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: Only after reading the answers did I understand what you probably mean by _“but with the use of attribute name in string”_. Please [see](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+property+by+string) [Dynamically access object property using variable](/q/4244896/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` **attribute** represents the **initial value** of the input.

The `value` **property** represents the **current value** of the input.

They are distinctly different things, even if they share a name.

There is no attribute that represents the current value.

You cannot use `getAttribute` to get the current value.

---

To read a property using a string variable containing the name, [use square bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).

```
input_obj["value"]
```