# Javascript setAttribute(value, name) input fields are not sending to BE on submission

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, setattribute

I am using the Amelia Calendar Plugin on my WordPress site.

I have custom fields enabled where I use `document.setAttribute(value, name)` however when I submit this form the JS `setAttribute` fields are not sending to the back end.

Here is the test domain I set up to take a look: http://s918546899.websitehome.co.uk/elementor-6

Here is the Javascript I have written to set the values in the custom fields:

```
if(window.location.href.includes("elementor-6")) {
// 1. set on click on next button once you land on page
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("am-button")[1].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()"); 
        console.log("onclick has been set")
    }, 3000);
}

// 2. call function that will set on click on next button for second form screen 
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("am-fs__main-heading-inner-title")[0].textContent != "Your Information") {
        setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("am-button")[1].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()"); }, 3000);
        console.log("onclick set again");
    } else {
        //document.getElementsByClassName("am-fs__main-heading-inner-title")[0].textContent == "Your Information" {
                
        // set text in input fields
        document.getElementsByClassName("el-input__inner")[3].setAttribute("value", "test");
        document.getElementsByClassName("el-input__inner")[4].setAttribute("value", "test2");
    }
}
```

I would be really grateful if someone could take a look and help with this.

This is also a test domain so happy to share the wp-admin credentials if someone wishes to take a look on the BE.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching an event, not setting attribute. This is done using the function `addEventListener`. Also consider using the more methodical `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector` instead  of `getElementsByClassName`.

Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector(".button-one").addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  console.log(this.innerText)
});

document.querySelectorAll(".button-two").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    console.log(this.innerText)
  });
})
```

```html
<button class="button-one">one</button>
<button class="button-two">two</button>
<button class="button-two">two again</button>
```

On the other hand, sometimes you might be tempted to make an inline `onclick` especially if you are echoing html from the server. In that case it would work but still it's not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to look at my question @IT goldman. The issue I am having isn't the eventListener or setting the function. It is more so when sending the ```setAttribute(value, name)``` field to the BE. It seems the form isn't registering when an input field has been populated with JS so when sent to the BE the field sends as ```""```

Comment: Wait, I think I understand. So are you essentially saying because it is a multistep form and I am using ```setAttribute``` and not adding an ```eventListener```, when I go to the next step of the form, it is not taking the string from those input fields along with the button click to go next?

Comment: No, that is irrelevant then. Maybe I didn't understand. But passing values thru a form can be done using `<input type="hidden" name="key" value="value">`. You might need to "manually" add them to the request if you're using Ajax.

Comment: So the ```setAttribute``` is correct. Can you shed some light on how to add them to the request and is it possible to check if the plugin is using AJAX?

Comment: yes it is using ajax. you can see by the network tab in the devtools. it looks like you are doing it wrong andin a patchy way. did you try reading the [custom-fields](https://wpamelia.com/custom-fields/) section of wpamelia docs?

Comment: Yes - so the custom fields work fine but I want to add my own text values in those fields with Javascript which is where the issue arises as the custom fields where I ```setAttribute``` the text to doesn't send to the backend. I think there may be a bigger issue. If you check the URL I have set the test form on, you will see when you press next on the 'Your Information' screen, it registers the ```setAttribute``` fields as empty and gives an error as 'This field is required'

Comment: 1. maybe try setting `element.value='test'` instead of `setAttribute`. according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3919313/3807365) it is more precise. 2. you can send me your server side credentials if you think it might help. 3. the custom fields don't have a `name` attribute. so it would be difficult to access them from server.