# Jquery output preview in realsrc

Tags: jquery, filereader

I'm trying to output the image preview in realsrc instead of src. Is that even possible?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
    output.realsrc = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL( $('#file')[0].files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, `output.realsrc` sets a *property* called "realsrc", not an attribute.
To set an attribute, use JavaScript's [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = document.getElementById('file');
var output = document.getElementById('output_image');

reader.onload = function() {
  output.setAttribute('realsrc', this.result);
  console.log(output.getAttribute('realsrc'));
}

file.addEventListener('change', function() {
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<img id="output_image">
```

Note that:

> ... when an element has id or another standard attribute, the corresponding property gets created. **But that doesn’t happen if the attribute is non-standard.** -- [HTML attributes](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties#html-attributes).

Also see:
[Javascript for adding a custom attribute to some elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757799/javascript-for-adding-a-custom-attribute-to-some-elements).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!