# How to remove an event listener and add the listener back on another element click

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple picture matching game and I will love to make sure when the picture is clicked once, the event listener is removed, this will help me stop the user from clicking on the same image twice to get a win, and then when the user clicks on another element the listener should be added back, I tried doing this with an if statement but the listener is only removed and never added back, I decided to reload the page which somehow makes it look like a solution but I need a better solution that can help me not to reload the page but add the listener back so that the element can be clicked again after the last else if statement run.

here is the sample code below.

```js
//Selecting query elements
const aniSpace = document.querySelector(".container");
const firstCard = document.querySelector("#fstcard");
const secondCard = document.querySelector("#sndcard");
const thirdCard = document.querySelector("#thrdcard");
const playGame = document.querySelector('#play');
const scores = document.querySelector('.scoreboard');

count = 0;
var firstIsClicked = false;
var isCat = false;
var isElephant = false;
var isDog = false;
var isButterfly = false;
var isEmpty = false;


const animatchApp = () => {

    const animals = {
        cat: {
            image: "asset/images/cat.png",
            name: "Cat"
        },
        dog: {
            image: "asset/images/puppy.png",
            name: "Dog"
        },
        elephant: {
            image: "asset/images/elephant.png",
            name: "Elephant"
        },
        butterfly: {
            image: "asset/images/butterfly.png",
            name: "butterfly"
        }
    }
var score = 0;
    firstCard.addEventListener('click', function firstBtn() {
        var type = animals.cat.name;
        if (firstIsClicked === true && isCat === true) {
            firstCard.innerHTML = `<img src="${animals.cat.image}">`;
            firstCard.classList.add('display');
            alert("You won");
            score = score + 50;
            console.log(score);
            document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
            firstIsClicked = false;
            isElephant = false;
            if (score >= 200){
                alert("You are unstoppable, Game won.");
                count = 0;
                score = 0;
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
                document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
                }
            firstCard.removeEventListener('click', firstBtn);
        } else if (firstIsClicked === false) {
            firstCard.innerHTML = `<img src="${animals.cat.image}">`;
            firstCard.classList.add('display');
            firstIsClicked = true;
            isCat = true;
            firstCard.removeEventListener('click', firstBtn);
        } else if (firstIsClicked === true && isCat != true) {
            alert("Not Matched");
            count++;
            document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
            firstCard.innerHTML = '';
            secondCard.innerHTML = '';
            thirdCard.innerHTML = '';
            
            firstCard.classList.remove('display');
            secondCard.classList.remove('display');
            thirdCard.classList.remove('display');
           
            firstIsClicked = false;
            isCat = false;
            isDog = false;
            isElephant = false;
            isButterfly = false;
            score = 0;
            document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
            location.reload(true);
        }
    })

    secondCard.addEventListener('click', function secondBtn() {
        var type = animals.elephant.name;
        if (firstIsClicked === true && isElephant === true) {
            secondCard.innerHTML = `<img src="${animals.elephant.image}">`;
            secondCard.classList.add('display');
            alert("You won");
            score = score + 50;
            console.log(score);
            document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
            firstIsClicked = false;
            isElephant = false;
            if (score >= 200){
                alert("You are unstoppable, Game won.");
                count = 0;
                score = 0;
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
                document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
                }
            secondCard.removeEventListener('click', secondBtn);
        } else if (firstIsClicked === false) {
            secondCard.innerHTML = `<img src="${animals.elephant.image}">`;
            secondCard.classList.add('display');
            firstIsClicked = true;
            isElephant = true;
            secondCard.removeEventListener('click', secondBtn);
        } else if (firstIsClicked === true && isElephant != true) {
            alert("Not Matched");
            count++;
            document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
            firstCard.innerHTML = '';
            secondCard.innerHTML = '';
            thirdCard.innerHTML = '';
            
            firstCard.classList.remove('display');
            secondCard.classList.remove('display');
            thirdCard.classList.remove('display');
            
            firstIsClicked = false;
            isCat = false;
            isDog = false;
            isElephant = false;
            isButterfly = false;
            score = 0;
            document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
            location.reload(true);
        }
    })
    
    thirdCard.addEventListener('click', function thirdBtn() {
        var type = animals.dog.name;
        if (firstIsClicked === true && isDog === true) {
            thirdCard.innerHTML = `<img src="${animals.dog.image}">`;
            thirdCard.classList.add('display');
            alert("You won");
            score = score + 50;
            console.log(score);
            document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
            firstIsClicked = false;
            isDog = false;
            if (score >= 200){
                alert("You are unstoppable, Game won.");
                count = 0;
                score = 0;
                document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
                document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
                }
            thirdCard.removeEventListener('click', thirdBtn);
        } else if (firstIsClicked === false) {
            thirdCard.innerHTML = `<img src="${animals.dog.image}">`;
            thirdCard.classList.add('display');
            firstIsClicked = true;
            isDog = true;
            thirdCard.removeEventListener('click', thirdBtn);
        } else if (firstIsClicked === true && isDog != true) {
            alert("Not Matched");
            count++;
            document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
            firstCard.innerHTML = '';
            secondCard.innerHTML = '';
            thirdCard.innerHTML = '';
           
            firstCard.classList.remove('display');
            secondCard.classList.remove('display');
            thirdCard.classList.remove('display');
            
            firstIsClicked = false;
            isCat = false;
            isDog = false;
            isElephant = false;
            isButterfly = false;
            score = 0;
            document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = score;
            location.reload(true);
        }
    })


    document.getElementById('attempts').innerHTML = count;
}

animatchApp();
```

```css
.h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: azure;
    background-image: url("");
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
}

.card1 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 150px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    border: 1px solid rgb(179, 177, 177);
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card2 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 150px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    border: 1px solid rgb(179, 177, 177);
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;}

.card3 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 150px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    border: 1px solid rgb(179, 177, 177);
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.scoreboard {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 150px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.display {
    background-color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="h1">Animatch</h1>
        <div class="first">
            <div class="card1" id="fstcard"></div>
            <div class="card1" id="sndcard"></div>
            <div class="card1" id="thrdcard"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="scoreboard">
        <p>
            <button id="play" onclick="animatchApp()">Play</button>
            <br>
            Score: <span id="scores">0</span>
            <br>
            Failed attempts: <span id="attempts"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: if i can see how your game works so i could suggest you better way to achieve it your current code is too big i believe it can be reduced drastically

Comment: Instead of adding and removing event listeners, add a *[custom tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769716/14958486)*, for example *data-accept-click*, and toggle or check the tag instead.

Comment: Okay, @AmirRahman should I create a fiddle or a GitHub project for you to see the code and assist me, because I will appreciate your help.

Comment: @Tsquare07 i wanted to know how your game works because your current snippet code is not working which is obvious so it will be usefull for suggesting any solution if we know exact goal or desired result more clearly

Comment: Okay, here is the game itself: https://jsfiddle.net/Iamtsquare07/4c9jo25w/16/ @AmirRahman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define function outside of `onclick` because you will need this function reference to remove or add it to eventlistener later
see a example below

```js
function onload(){
    var main = document.querySelector(".main"),
        btns = main.querySelectorAll(".buttons input"),
        box = main.querySelector(".box")       

    btns[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
        box.addEventListener("click",functionForEvent)
    })

    btns[1].addEventListener("click",function(){
        box.removeEventListener("click",functionForEvent)
    })

    function functionForEvent(e){
        console.log("clicked")
    }
}
onload()
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="box" style="height:120px;width:120px;border:1px solid black;">Click Me</div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="button" value="Add Event">
        <input type="button" value="Remove Event">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gives me the kind of advice I need to solve the issue, If you have a similar problem, make sure you add the event listener outside the onclick as Amir suggested, it work for me.

Comment: @Tsquare07 your most wellcome

Comment: @Tsquare07 see i have created one with some technique to reduce hardcoding everything . take a look at codes i have provided comments in each section where needed for you understand easily if there's still any confusion ask freely https://jsfiddle.net/amirrahman132132/7rw24x6o/5/

Comment: Thanks @AmirRahman I learn a lot from that, I will take some time to go through the code more carefully and give you some feedback or questions, I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, that shows how to remove the click event from the item clicked and add it to the other items.

It colors the items that can be clicked *green*, and the item that can't be clicked *red*.

To keep the example short, it doesn't check, if the elements it operates on, are well defined.

```js
function myonload() {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv');
    for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        let elem = elems[i];
        elem.addEventListener('click', mydiv_clicked);
    }
}
function mydiv_clicked(e) {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv');
    for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        let elem = elems[i];
        if(elem == e.target) {
            elem.removeEventListener('click', mydiv_clicked);
            elem.classList.add('mycolor_clicked');
            elem.classList.remove('mycolor');
            // Do additional logic here
        } else {
            elem.addEventListener('click', mydiv_clicked);
            elem.classList.remove('mycolor_clicked');
            elem.classList.add('mycolor');
            // Do additional logic here
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
    height:30px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.mycolor {
    background-color:#00ff00;
}
.mycolor_clicked {
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myonload()">
    <div class="mydiv mycolor">First area</div>
    <div class="mydiv mycolor">Second area</div>
    <div class="mydiv mycolor">Third area</div>
</body>
```

The example shown here does not need to check if an event handler already exists, as adding the same event handler twice, replaces the existing one.

You could also add a custom attribute to your elements and toggle it, instead of adding and removing event listeners as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757848/14958486) and name your attribute *data-something*, for example *data-can-be-clicked*.